# How to create calculated Geometry column that ignores NULL values in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, ssms, geography

I have a 'Sites' table with columns for Latitude and Longitude in SSMS 2017. I would like to add a calculated column of Geography data type based on the Latitude and Longitude values. I have used this command:

```
ALTER TABLE Sites 
    ADD Geo2 AS (geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(Sites.Latitude Sites.Longitude)', 4326))
```

This command completes successfully, but when I try to select * from the table, it returns the error shown in the screenshot [failed select command error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLJNb.png). I suspect it is because some sites do not have Lat/Long data (are NULL values). Is there a way around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try filtering the values first. Something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE Sites 
 ADD Geo2 AS IIF(Latitude  IS NOT NULL AND Longitude IS NOT NULL, [geography]::Point(Longitude,Latitude,4326), NULL)
```